# Postorder in BST

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, postorder

[image: BST TREE]

> write the post order of the above BST

I,m confusing it starts with 50 or 60

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you don't show the code?

Comment: What is confusing about the problem?

Comment: I added image above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Post order" means that a parent is always visited *after* ("post") its children are visited.. So if you would start with 50, you cannot visit 60 anymore, as that would violate that rule.

The post order thus starts like this: 60, 50, 80, ...

As this is an assignment, please figure out the rest yourself, just making sure you always abide to the above rule.